# Migration com possível perda de dados

Tags: c#, migrations, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Ao gerar uma atualização do `db` que resulta em possível perda de dados `efcore` mostra o alerta:

> An operation was scaffolded that may result in the loss of data.
>   Please review the migration for accuracy.

*(Neste caso específico foi removido um campo da tabela)*

Quando isso ocorre a estrutura do `db` não é alterada.

Pra contornar esta situação eu removo todos os `migrations` gerados e gero um novo, com isso, a nova estrutura é gerada com sucesso.

*(Como o aplicativo não esta em produção, até o momento não me preocupava em recriar o `db`)*

Gostaria de saber a forma correta de resolver este tipo de problema, ou seja, forçar atualização da tabela mesmo sabendo da perda de dados. Ou se existe uma forma melhor de resolver este tipo de situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas formas:

```
Remove-Migration
```

Remove a *Migration* com problemas. Remove também o *Snapshot* de banco de dados se for o caso.

Para desfazer a *Migration*:

```
Update-Database -Migration:NomeDeUmaMigrationAnterior
```

Para desfazer todas as *Migrations*, use:

```
Update-Database -Migration:0
```

Repare que `Update-Database` não apaga arquivos de *Migration*. Se aproxima da solução que você sugeriu na pergunta.

Procurando sobre os mecanismos de *Migrations* automáticas para o EF Core, [achei este comentário aqui](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6214#issuecomment-239519498). Aparentemente, a equipe da Microsoft não pretende implementar suporte a *Migrations* automáticas. No EF6, a configuração de *Migrations* automáticas seria minha sugestão.

Comment: Então não há como `Forçar atualização da tabela` para apagar um campo ou um índice por exemplo sendo necessária a recriação total do banco? Se eu apagar todas as `migrations` as tabela em produção certamente ficarão com campos/índices desnecessários correto @cigano-morrison-mendez?

Comment: Correto. Como tenho recomendado nesses últimos meses, tudo que envolve o *Stack* .NET Core ainda está instável, em desenvolvimento, então o recomendado é esperar e não fazer sistemas grandes e críticos para produção até que o *Stack* esteja estável. Possivelmente novas funcionalidades virão para substituir funcionalidades antigas (como o *data loss* e as migrações automáticas).

Comment: Adendo: futuramente terei que atualizar esta resposta porque os mecanismos que devem sanar sua dúvida ainda não existem.